# How to resolve 'KeyError' in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The program I am trying to develop, is about a find rsi divergence.It crashes when I run the program.When the interval is equal to 60 minutes, the program is active. When I change the time to 15 minutes, the program gives an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import ta

ticker=yf.Ticker("ADA-USD")

data=ticker.history(period="10d",interval='15m')
data.rename(columns={"Close":"close","High":"high","Low":"low","Open":"open"},inplace=True)
data.index=range(1,len(data)+1)

rsi_peroid=14
data["rsi"+str(rsi_peroid)]=ta.momentum.RSIIndicator(data["close"],rsi_peroid).rsi()
data.dropna(inplace=True)
```

```
divergence_point=[]
rsi_val=data["rsi14"]
loop=10
for i in range(loop,len(data)-1):
    recent_rsi=rsi_val[i-loop:i]
    recent_price=data["close"].iloc[i-loop:i]
    if (data["close"].iloc[i] < min(recent_price) and rsi_val[i] >= min((recent_rsi)+2) or data["close"].iloc[i] > max(recent_price) and rsi_val[i]<= max(recent_rsi)-2):
        divergence_point.append(i)
        
data["Divergence"]=False

data.loc[divergence_point,"Divergence"]=True
```

When I run the program, it faces an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3653, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3652 try:
-> 3653     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3654 except KeyError as err:

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2606, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2630, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 11

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[264], line 7
      5     recent_rsi=rsi_val[i-loop:i]
      6     recent_price=data["close"].iloc[i-loop:i]
----> 7     if (data["close"].iloc[i] < min(recent_price) and rsi_val[i] >= min((recent_rsi)+2) or data["close"].iloc[i] > max(recent_price) and rsi_val[i]<= max(recent_rsi)-2):
      8         divergence_point.append(i)
     10 data["Divergence"]=False

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1007, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
   1004     return self._values[key]
   1006 elif key_is_scalar:
-> 1007     return self._get_value(key)
   1009 if is_hashable(key):
   1010     # Otherwise index.get_value will raise InvalidIndexError
   1011     try:
   1012         # For labels that don't resolve as scalars like tuples and frozensets

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1116, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1113     return self._values[label]
   1115 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1116 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1118 if is_integer(loc):
   1119     return self._values[loc]

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3655, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3653     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3654 except KeyError as err:
-> 3655     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3656 except TypeError:
   3657     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3658     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3659     #  the TypeError.
   3660     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 11
```

When the interval is equal to 60 minutes, the program is active. When I change the time to 15 minutes, the program gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to access an index (11) that does not exist in such pd.Series (`rsi_val`).
Your loop starts at i=10 and increases by one each iteration. rsi_val[11] does not exist because you dropped nans with `data.dropna(inplace=True)` and series' index starts from index 14.
I guess it does not crash in the first iteration (i=10) because `data["close"].iloc[i] < min(recent_price)` evaluates to `False` and second comparison is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
hsh = {"123": "Res"}
key = "123"
if key in hsh:
  print(hsh[key])
```

In you case you should check data["close"]

```
if "close" in data:
      # You code
```